# How can I use a variable to complete an insert in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures

```
CREATE DEFINER=`blah`@`%` PROCEDURE `INSTERTTHESE`(IN issuerNUM INT(20))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `DB`.`TABLE` (`id`,`minValue`)
VALUES  (issuerNUM,'700000'issuerNUM'0000000');
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: trying to use issuerNUM to complete the insert value 700000'issuerNUM'0000000

Comment: Sorry this is MySQL

Answer (score 0):

CONCAT('700000',issuerNUM,'0000000')